# jQuery DataTables - Cannot reinitialise DataTable

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, datatables

I'm making a statements page in a spring 4.x application using jQuery DataTables to render the statements.

I have the following object returned by the server after parsing thru the Jackson message converter.

```
{
    "data":[
        {
            "desc":"SUBWAY        00501197 BRONX        NYUS",
            "amount":"-",
            "date":"5.72"
        },
        {
            "desc":"MIDTOWN COMICS         NEW YORK     NYUS",
            "amount":"-",
            "date":"73.32"
        },
        {
            "desc":"GOOGLE *PlayDog Soft   GOOGLE.COM/CHCAUS",
            "amount":"-",
            "date":"1.99"
        },
        {
            "desc":"BIMG PRIMARY CARE      NEW YORK     NYUS",
            "amount":"-",
            "date":"25.00"
        },
        {
            "desc":"GOOGLE *PlayDog Soft   GOOGLE.COM/CHCAUS",
            "amount":"-",
            "date":"1.99"
        },
        {
            "desc":"GOOGLE *PlayDog Soft   GOOGLE.COM/CHCAUS",
            "amount":"-",
            "date":"1.99"
        },
        {
            "desc":"Walgreens Speci 205 8THNEW YORK     NYUS",
            "amount":"-",
            "date":"10.00"
        },
        {
            "desc":"GOOGLE *SGN Games      GOOGLE.COM/CHCAUS",
            "amount":"-",
            "date":"9.99"
        },
        {
            "desc":"REDBOX *DVD RENTAL     866-733-2693 ILUS",
            "amount":"-",
            "date":"35.93"
        },
        {
            "desc":"SHUN FA RELAXING CENTE NEW YORK     NYUS",
            "amount":"-",
            "date":"20.00"
        },
        {
            "desc":"CHIPOTLE 0590          NEW YORK     NYUS",
            "amount":"-",
            "date":"9.00"
        },
        {
            "desc":"CHIPOTLE 0590          NEW YORK     NYUS",
            "amount":"-",
            "date":"9.00"
        },
        {
            "desc":"ALEX CLEANERS          BRONX        NYUS",
            "amount":"-",
            "date":"58.95"
        },
        {
            "desc":"SUBWAY        00501197 BRONX        NYUS",
            "amount":"-",
            "date":"5.17"
        },
        {
            "desc":"PAYPAL *LAROMANAAPA    4029357733   CAUS",
            "amount":"-",
            "date":"103.20"
        },
        {
            "desc":"GOOGLE *PlayDog Soft   GOOGLE.COM/CHCAUS",
            "amount":"-",
            "date":"1.99"
        },
        {
            "desc":"GOOGLE *PlayDog Soft   GOOGLE.COM/CHCAUS",
            "amount":"-",
            "date":"1.99"
        },
        {
            "desc":"GOOGLE *SGN Games      GOOGLE.COM/CHCAUS",
            "amount":"-",
            "date":"4.99"
        },
        {
            "desc":"GOOGLE *SGN Games      GOOGLE.COM/CHCAUS",
            "amount":"-",
            "date":"4.99"
        },
        {
            "desc":"LA ISLA RESTAURANT #2  NEW YORK     NYUS",
            "amount":"-",
            "date":"12.75"
        },
        {
            "desc":"GOOGLE *PlayDog Soft   GOOGLE.COM/CHCAUS",
            "amount":"-",
            "date":"1.99"
        },
        {
            "desc":"GOOGLE *PlayDog Soft   GOOGLE.COM/CHCAUS",
            "amount":"-",
            "date":"1.99"
        },
        {
            "desc":"REDBOX *DVD RENTAL     866-733-2693 ILUS",
            "amount":"-",
            "date":"7.62"
        },
        {
            "desc":"GOOGLE *PlayDog Soft   GOOGLE.COM/CHCAUS",
            "amount":"-",
            "date":"1.99"
        },
        {
            "desc":"GOOGLE *PlayDog Soft   GOOGLE.COM/CHCAUS",
            "amount":"-",
            "date":"1.99"
        },
        {
            "desc":"GOOGLE *PlayDog Soft   GOOGLE.COM/CHCAUS",
            "amount":"-",
            "date":"1.99"
        },
        {
            "desc":"GOOGLE *PlayDog Soft   GOOGLE.COM/CHCAUS",
            "amount":"-",
            "date":"1.99"
        },
        {
            "desc":"GOOGLE *PlayDog Soft   GOOGLE.COM/CHCAUS",
            "amount":"-",
            "date":"3.99"
        },
        {
            "desc":"GOOGLE *PlayDog Soft   GOOGLE.COM/CHCAUS",
            "amount":"-",
            "date":"1.99"
        },
        {
            "desc":"GOOGLE *PlayDog Soft   GOOGLE.COM/CHCAUS",
            "amount":"-",
            "date":"1.99"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I'm trying to pass this to data table as follows. But I get an error.

```
$('#example').dataTable(data)
```

But it gives me an error shown below:

> DataTables warning: table id=example - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3.

Also the table rendered has data in place of column names and looks just wrong.

Below is my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getStmt", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody HashMap<String,ArrayList<UserStatement>> getStatement(@RequestParam(required = true) String name, @RequestParam(required = true) String month, HttpServletRequest request, Model model){
        System.out.println(name+", "+month+"");
        User user = userDao.findUserByName(name);
        ArrayList<UserStatement> s=new ArrayList<UserStatement>();
        if (user != null && user.getUser_token()!=null) {
            s = (ArrayList<UserStatement>) userDao.getUserSelectedStatement(user.getUser_token(), 07, 2015);

        }else{
            UserStatement us =new UserStatement();
            us.setAmount("A user token could not be found for the user ");
            s.add(us);
        }
        HashMap<String, ArrayList<UserStatement>> h=new HashMap<String, ArrayList<UserStatement>>();
        h.put("data", s);

        return h;
    }
```

Below is my Ajax function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var today = new Date();
    var month=today.getMonth();
    var name="test";

    $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "getStmt.ajax",
           data: "name="+name+"&month="+month,
           success: function(msg){
               $('#stdata').html( '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example"></table>' );
             var data1 = JSON.stringify(msg);
                console.log(data1);
                console.log(data1.data);
             console.log( "Data Saved: " + msg );
             $('#example').dataTable( {
                 "aaData": data,
                 "aoColumns": [
                             {"sTitle": "Description"},
                             {"sTitle": "Amount" },
                             {"sTitle": "Date" }
                         ]
             } );
           },
           error: function(msg){
               var data = msg;
                 console.log( "There was an error: " + msg );
                 $('#stdata').dataTable( {
                     "ajax": data,
                     "columns": [
                                 { "title": "Description" },
                                 { "title": "Amount" },
                                 { "title": "Date" },
                                 { "title": "Balance" }
                             ]
                 } );
           }
         }); 
});
```

and html:

```
<div class="panel-body">

                        <div id="stdata">
                        </div>
</div>
```

the table should sit inside `stdata` div.

How can I get this to work? I also want it in such a way that if a user changes the date selected in a drop-down list, the table should be repopulated thru Ajax for that date.

Comment: Did you check the link mentioned in the alert message?

Comment: hmm.. yes i did. Perhaps i was trying to initiate datatables after it was already initiated and that caused the message. But the issue of data not being read correctly still persists. It still renders column data for columns

Answer (score 8):

#### SOLUTION 1

Use [`ajax.data`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data) option to add additional parameters that would be sent to the server.

That way you don't need to re-initialize the table which makes the code much simple.

For example:

```js
$('#example').DataTable({
    ajax: {
        url: "/script.php",
        data: function(d){
            d.select1 = $('#example-select1').val();            
            d.select2 = $('#example-select2').val();            
        }
    }
});

$('#example-select1, #example-select2').on('change', function(){
    $('#example').DataTable().ajax.reload(); 
});
```

where `example-select1`, `example-select2` are IDs of your drop-downs.

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aju0oozb/) for code and demonstration.

#### SOLUTION 2

Use [`clear()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/clear%28%29) along with [`rows.add()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/rows.add%28%29) to clear the table and add new data for DataTables 1.10+. For DataTables 1.9, use [`fnClearTable`](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref) and [`fnAddData`](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref) respectively.

**To add data to existing table (for DataTables 1.10+)**:

```
$('#example').DataTable().clear();
$('#example').DataTable().rows.add(msg.data);
```

where `msg` is a variable holding response from the server.

#### SOLUTION 3

Use [`bDestroy`](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref) (for DataTables 1.9) or [`destroy`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/destroy) (for DataTables 1.10+) options to destroy any existing table matching the selector and replace with the new options.

**To reinitialize the table (for DataTables 1.10+)**:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
   "destroy": true,
   "data": msg.data,
   "columns": [
      {"title": "Description"},
      {"title": "Amount" },
      {"title": "Date" }
   ]
});
```

where `msg` is a variable holding response from the server.

Comment: is there an example you can guide me towards.. for updating the server with the newly added rows on add and save event

Comment: @DJR, I just re-read your question and I think there is a much simple solution than trying to re-initialize the table, I will post an example soon.

Comment: @DJR, just added an example for solution #1 which I would recommend to use for performance and minimal code to mantain.